# Jasper Reports summarize all groups before showing group details

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there any way I can show total balances for all groups and then show details for each account?

For Example, Say I have 4 Accounts, I would like the following

**Accounts Summary Header**

- Summary of Account A
- Summary of Account B
- Summary of Account C
- Summary of Account D

**Accounts Summary Footer**

Account A Details...

Account B Details...

Account C Details...

Account D Details...

---

The report I am using now groups by the field that separates these accounts but is repeating in the following way:

Summary of Account A

Account A Details

Summary of Account B

Account B Details

...etc

I have thought of considering a subreport for the summary section but it would end up being the same query used for the details section which would make it redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Studio has the idea of **bands** on which you drag and drop labels in the `Design` tab.

In general the solution would be to use `Summary` band, which would hold the details of accounts.

If you put everything in `Detail 1` band, jasper will repeat that to fill all the page content and will not repeat them.

Also [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/understanding-bands) you can find more details about the bands usage.

Quick info about the summary tab:

> Summary
>
> The summary band allows you to insert fields containing total
>   calculations, means, or any other information you want to include at
>   the end of the report.

Comment: ill try this but I'm interested in showing them at the start of the report. Does Jasper allow you to rearrange bands?

Comment: then put details in `Detail 1` band and summary in `Summary` band, or opposite. no need to rearrange the bands :)

Comment: Tried placing the summary in `Detail 1` but it repeats for every row in the group and if I place it in `Summary` it shows up in the end

Comment: but you have separated both of them so they do not overlap. what else do you need?

Comment: to show the summary of all members (accounts) in the group followed by the details for each member in the group. Your solution did separate them but the summary section repeated multiple times when placed in details. I'm looking into the `Group Changes` and `Evaluation Time` properties to see if they help.